# How to completely visualize the component stack trace in react bundled by webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, error-handling

I utilize webpack as a bundler. When errors occur in my app, I want to be able to see the component stack trace to determine precisely which file that error is in (for others that are using my application as well). But if you notice, the component stack trace is tracking back to the webpack.bundle.js file. How do I change this to be more clear.

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2560 The above error occurred in one of your React components:

    at li
    at ul
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:51064:13)
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:50842:74)
    at ErrorBoundary (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:100639:37)
    at div
    at __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundary.
```